# how are errors handled differently between the following code samples

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, axios

I'm trying to understand how promises and async await work.  I have three implementations and was wondering if they are equivalent or if there's a major difference in what's happening:

original implementation:

```
function sendData(url,emailPass){

    let bodyFormData = new FormData()
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(emailPass)) {
        console.log(key,value)
        bodyFormData.append(key,value)
    }    
        
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    })
        .then(function (response){
            console.log(response.data)
            // do stuff with the data   
        })
        .catch(function(response){
            console.log(response)
            // do stuff with the error
        })    
}
```

second implementation:

```
async function sendData2(url,emailPass){

    let bodyFormData = new FormData()
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(emailPass)) {
        //console.log(key,value)
        bodyFormData.append(key,value)
    }

    try{
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: bodyFormData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
            })
                return response.data
    }catch(e){
        const error =['FATAL ERROR: See Admin', e]
        return error
    }
}
```

third implementation:

```
function sendData3(url,emailPass){

    let bodyFormData = new FormData()
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(emailPass)) {
        //console.log(key,value)
        bodyFormData.append(key,value)
    }

    return axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: bodyFormData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
            })
                .then(function(response){
                    return response.data
                })
                .catch(function(response){
                    return response
                })
}
```

Comment: The first sample of `sendData()` has no `return`, so it always returns `undefined.

Comment: I updated the question, I had made a mistake in the original implementation.  It's true there's no return in the original but we are just moving the code to the do stuff with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Make promise-returning synchronous by suspending execution until the returned promise is fulfilled or rejected. The resolved value of the promise is treated as the return value of the await expression. Use of async and await enables the use of ordinary try/catch blocks around asynchronous code.

`async`
`try`
`await`
`await` <----- erro
`await`
`await`
`catch`

When Promise can be resolved by then() or chaining.

> `then().`
> `then().` <----- error ( will stop chaining)
> `then().`
> `then().`
> `catch( error for all )`

Comment: how is that different from the third implementation?

Comment: It all depends on the implementation if you are making a request to the server with a process and a resolution of then (). cash () is more than enough to not load the thread with unnecessary code. But if they make more than two simultaneous requests, where there is the possibility that one or more fails and the execution thread have to continue to resolve the promises, it needs a try/catch and everything in an async with the various awaits, taking advantage of resources.

Comment: `return` is not necessary. I test a few requests one with and the other without.

Comment: `await` does not suspend execution.